# Extension (or "counterexample") of the Schwarz reflection principle

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, reflection

The usual statement for Schwarz reflection principle on a general analytic arc is something along these lines:

> Given a holomorphic function $f$ on a region $\Omega$, assume that
>
> 1. The function has a continuous extention to an analytic arc $\gamma$ on $\partial \Omega$
> 2. $f(\gamma)$ is an analytic arc
> 3. $f(\Omega)$ is on one side of $f(\gamma)$
>
> Then $f$ has an analytic extension across $\gamma$ (except at most its endpoints).

While the first two assumptions are clear to me, I do not *understand* the third one: it is not a requirement that we can trace back to the "original" Schwarz reflection principle.

Is there some deep reason, perhaps geometric, for this addition, or is it not strictly necessary, and thus we have some generalizations of the principle which weaken this assumption?

Comment: It's not necessary. You can reflect across $\gamma$ and $f(\gamma)$ just fine, whether or not $f(\Omega)$ lies on one side of $f(\gamma)$ (but that condition makes drawing things easier).

Comment: @DanielFischer I see. Indeed, going back to read Lang's proof of the statement, I think that the same proof applies for the general statement. Do you have any idea then of why they would restrict themselves to this additional hypotesis?

Comment: No idea, really.

Comment: However, we do need the hypotesis that $\Omega$ lies on one side of $\gamma$