# Extension of $f\in\mathcal{H}(\mathbb{D})$ that maps a circular arc to an analytic curve

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, reflection, analytic-continuation

Let $f\in\mathcal{H}(\mathbb{D})$ (i.e. it is a holomorphic function on the open unit disc) and $\gamma$ a (open) circular arc $\in \partial\mathbb{D}$ such that $f\in\mathcal{C}^0(\mathbb{D}\cup\gamma$); $f(\gamma)$ is an analytic curve. Prove that $f$ has an analytic extension across $\gamma$

My attempt:
Since $f(\gamma)$ is an analytic curve, we know that there exists a conformal map $\varphi:A\to \mathbb{C}; \varphi((0,1))=f(\gamma)$. Then, considering $g(z):=\varphi^{-1}\circ f(z)$ (on $f^{-1}(\varphi(A))$), it satisfies the hypotesis of Schwarz's reflection principle for the circle, and so it is extendable.

Applying $\varphi$ to the extension, we obtain an extension of $f$

Is my attempt right? Are there other way of proving it?

I am aware of the reflection principle for analytic arcs, but I am not sure on how to prove that $f(\mathbb{D})$ lies on a side of $f(\gamma)$ and so I cannot use it.

Comment: The exercise shows that the condition that $f(\mathbb{D})$ lie on one side of the arc is useless. I wonder who added it to the statement of the reflection principle.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this? I tried looking for it online but I didn't manage to find such a generalization

Comment: Not really a reference, but the issue [came up here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3685693/extension-or-counterexample-of-the-schwarz-reflection-principle) a couple of days ago. If you look at the proof, can you find a place where it's needed?